# Jira JQL - Show all child tasks

Tags: jira, jql, jira-filter

I am trying to display all my tasks under 3 levels of Macro-Feature and/or Epic Link, as my organization look like this :

- Macro Feature
- Epic Link (= feature) => Epic Link (= subfeature) => Tasks
- or directly Epic Link => Tasks

I want to see both levels, how can I achieve this please ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, you have an epic, linked to another epic? Also, are you using Jira Server or Jira Cloud (with atlassian.net in the URL)?

Comment: Hello yes that's it, we have two levels of epic, some tasks are in the top level epic when you don't exactly know what feature it is, and some in Epic of Epic (link child task of). We use Jira Server, i think i need a rule that shows child task for N levels no matter the issuetype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In pure Jira Server, it is not possible to follow the links, you will have to query issues assigned to the epic, take their issue keys or ids and build a combined query. Let's say you have top-level epics called TOP-1 and TOP-2, you will have to run a query:

```
issue in linkedIssues("TOP-1", "is task of") and issuetype = Epic
```

take the returned issue keys, repeat for TOP-2, this will give you the second level epics, let's say SUB-1 and SUB-2, then you need to run a query like:

```
"Epic Link" in (TOP-1, TOP-2) or "Epic Link" in (SUB-1, SUB-2)
```

this will give you issues assigned to those epics, without subtasks. Quite cumbersome and requires manual updating, definitely not worth doing.

The alternative would be getting a plugin that extends JQL functionality, like [JQL Search Extensions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214791/jql-search-extensions-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview). Then you could nest the JQL queries like:

```
issue in allIssuesInEpic("TOP-1", "TOP2") or (issue in allIssuesInEpic(issue in linkedBy("TOP-1", "TOP-2", "is task of")))
```

Where first part of the query `issue in allIssuesInEpic("TOP-1", "TOP2")` returns the issues directly assigned to the TOP-1 or TOP-2 epics, and the second part `issue in allIssuesInEpic(issue in linkedBy("TOP-1", "TOP-2", "is task of"))` finds the epics linked as "is task of" with top-level epics and then finds all the issues with subtasks assigned to those second level epics.
You will need to extend the query for every level of nesting, with the structure you have described, above query will do what you need. However, if you will add the third level of nesting then you will have to extend the query like:

```
issue in allIssuesInEpic("TOP-1", "TOP2") or (issue in allIssuesInEpic(issue in linkedBy("key in (TOP-1, TOP2) or issue in linkedBy("TOP-1", "TOP-2", "is task of")", "is task of")))
```

You can make it more readable by creating filters for each level of nesting, for example, create a filter called Features:

```
key in (TOP-1, TOP-2)
```

then create a filter called sub-features:

```
issue in linkedBy("filter = Features", "is task of")
```

then create a final query like:

```
issue in allIssuesInEpic("filter = \"Features\" or filter = \"sub-features\"")
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not help :/ I am now doing something like this issue in linkedIssues("id-12428", "is parent task of") OR issueFunction in issuesInEpics("id = id-12428") where the first part show me the epic and macro-features, and the other one show me the issues in the Epic/Macro Feature. But I need to copy paste it a lot of times :/

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wrote. In pure Jira Server this will require a lot of manual work. To have it automated you need to install a plugin. Apparently, you have one already, issueFunction in issuesInEpics comes from the script runner plugin. Sadly, I have no experience with script runner so I can't help, probably you can contact their support and they will help you out.